# SQL Server 2005 Setup Problem

Tags: sql-server-2005

When I setup SQL Server 2005 this problem appear

> Minimum Hardware Requirement (Warning)
>   Messages Minimum Hardware Requirement
>
> The current system does not meet the
>   minimum hardware requirements for this
>   SQL Server release. For detailed
>   hardware and software requirements,
>   see the readme file or SQL Server
>   Books Online.

and I continued setup but I could not found SQL Server Management Studio tools in start menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, you have missed installing SSMS. You can go through the install process again (you don't need to uninstall, just run it again), except this time make sure you put a check mark next to the Management tools when you do feature selections. I'd tell you exactly where it is but i only have a SQL2008 install on hand at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is not completely installed, I suggest you to update all feature in your OS.

Comment: This is not a good answer - it has nothing to do with the OS.

Answer (score 0):

may be you installed Express edition? 
also Management Studio is free, you can download it from [link text](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=c243a5ae-4bd1-4e3d-94b8-5a0f62bf7796&displaylang=en)

Comment: I setup sql server2005 x86 full